# How to lock or disable firefox using webextensions?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm making a firefox addon using webextensions and I need to be able at some point to completely prevent the user from browsing any page until they provide some input.

Is there any way this can be done in webextensions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support for this.  You could perhaps hack something up with the webRequest api to block outgoing network requests but that would not block things like internal pages, cached requests, etc.  The browser is deliberately built to avoid these sorts of modal interactions, I would urge you to rethink your overall approach.